# Is this a complete sentence or two?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, errors, is-it-a-sentence

Given the example (from a British novel, *The Secret Intensity of Everyday Life*)

> Well **what did I expect who said it would be easy**? I will not let this defeat me. I will persist.

Is the first sentence a complete sentence? If yes, then does *who* take a role of relative pronoun? Can it be separated from the antecedent, *I*?

Or are these two sentences and the writer intentionally omits a punctuation mark
to get the protagonist’s rapid thinking across?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is grammatically correct, but possibly not in the way intended by the author. The sentence

> Well what did I expect who said it would be easy?

can mean the same as the reordered sentence

> Well what did I, **who said it would be easy**, expect?

When read this way, *who* certainly is a relative pronoun which refers back to *I*.

Having reviewed the [context at *Google Book Search*](http://books.google.com/books?id=QHeWkb11B4kC&pg=PT51&dq=%22Well+what+did+I+expect+who+said+it+would+be+easy?%22) I must say there is a real possibility the sentence is worded and punctuated as intended. There is a stream-of-consciousness approach to the text. There are sentence fragments and other deliberate irregularities of text flow and punctuation, even on the same page as the quoted sentence.

Comment: +1 for including the link to the original, and pointing out the relevence of the surrounding text to answer to a question like this. Correctness is seldom fully determined in a vacuum.

Answer (score 2):

It is two sentences. It should read:

> Well, what did I expect? Who said it would be easy?

I don't know what effect the writer was going for, but muddled thought might be it, yes.

Comment: Caught me - I actually started to edit.

Comment: His keyboard might have malfunctioned at the time of writing this part of the book.